# Sort text file in Python

Tags: python, sorting, text-files

Here's my .txt file

```
-22, www 1213
-25, ttt 1234
-20, yyy 8883
```

I want to order the lines based on the first number.

I tried like this:

```
f = open('file_.txt','rb')
text = f.readlines()
sorted(text, key=lambda row: row[0], reverse=True)
```

but the order is the same.
Using a variation for the sorted line

```
sorted(text, key=lambda row: float(row[0]), reverse=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: -
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sorted(text, key=lambda row: float(row.split()[0].rstrip(',')), reverse=True)
```

The problem was that you were sorting by the first character, you want the first word (without the comma), you could also split by the comma.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your sorting lambda isn't working is because row[0] is the first character, not the first value.  You could change it to row.split(',')[0], and it will work as intended.  Also, it's best practice to use the with statement for opening files.

```
with open('file_.txt','rb'):
    text = f.readlines()
sorted(text, key=lambda row: row.split(',')[0], reverse=True)
```

In your second example, you're getting the value error for the same reason, you're essentially saying float("-22, www 1213"). if you really wanted to do that it would be

```
    float(row.split(',')[0])
```

and if there might be whitespace:

```
    float(row.split(',')[0].strip())
```